# How to change css in prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Recently I started to work with prestashop 1.7. 
Does anyone know how to force recompilation of css by changing the ../_dev/css/theme.scss?

I try:

```
#wrapper {background: red;}
```

But in ../assets/css/theme.css remains

```
#wrapper {background: #ebebeb;}
```

Answer (score 0):

compiled by Webpack from the _dev files.